# How to compute real return including expense ratio

Tags: calculation, index-fund, rate-of-return, expense-ratio

I am currently hesitating between 2 similar International Index Fund, FSIVX and FIENX.

FSIVX have an expense ratio of 0.12% while FIENX have 0.63%.
I can try to compare them side by side on google finance https://www.google.com/finance?q=fienx&ei=BubEVpHrIMmxiwK8mJugDg

But my understanding is that this give the actual fund return without taking into account expense ratio.

What tool or formula can I use to compare the real expected return on investment for the 2 Funds for X number of year.

Comment: No, the reported prices of the mutual funds are _after_ the expense ratio has been accounted for. The _actual_ return of the fund would be higher, but you never get to see the exact numbers, and what you, as a consumer and shareholder, get to see are the returns as they will affect your personal finances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returns reported by mutual funds to shareholders, google, etc. are computed *after* all the funds' costs, including

- The expense ratio
- The 12b-1 fee, if any
- The transactions costs of the fund, which are not publicly disclosed but which you do have to pay

Therefore the returns you see on google finance are the returns you would actually have gotten.